# Cannot run TypeORM migrations by specific connection with Datasources

Tags: node.js, nestjs, datasource, typeorm

Using typeorm v under 0.3.0 if we had orm config like this:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    type: strict('DATABASE_TYPE'),
    host: strict('DATABASE_HOST'),
    username: strict('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
    password: strict('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
    database: strict('DATABASE_DATABASE'),
    port: strict('DATABASE_PORT'),
    synchronize: false,
    entities: [strict('DATABASE_ENTITIES')],
    migrations: [strict('DATABASE_MIGRATIONS')],
    migrationsRun: strict('DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_RUN') === 'true',
    migrationsTableName: process.env.DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_TABLE_NAME,
    cli: {
      migrationsDir: strict('DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_DIR'),
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'accountDbConnection',
    type: strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_TYPE'),
    host: strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_HOST'),
    username: strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME'),
    password: strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD'),
    database: strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_DATABASE'),
    port: strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_PORT'),
    synchronize: false,
    entities: [strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_ENTITIES')],
    migrations: [strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_MIGRATIONS')],
    migrationsRun: strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_MIGRATIONS_RUN') === 'true',
    migrationsTableName: process.env.DATABASE_ACCOUNT_MIGRATIONS_TABLE_NAME,
    cli: {
      migrationsDir: strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_MIGRATIONS_DIR'),
    },
  },
];
```

We could run migrations by specific connection using these npm scripts:

```
"typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register  ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
"typeorm:account": "node --require ts-node/register  ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js -c accountDbConnection",
"migrations:run": "npm run build && npm run typeorm migration:run",
"migrations:run:account": "npm run build && npm run typeorm:account migration:run",
```

Here have 'default' and 'accountDbConnection' and 'migration:run' script works well.

But using datasets if we export array of datasets it's not working as expected:

```
export default [
  new DataSource({
    type: strict('DATABASE_TYPE') as any,
    host: strict('DATABASE_HOST'),
    username: strict('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
    password: strict('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
    database: strict('DATABASE_DATABASE'),
    port: +strict('DATABASE_PORT'),
    synchronize: false,
    entities: [strict('DATABASE_ENTITIES')],
    migrations,
    migrationsRun: strict('DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_RUN') === 'true',
    migrationsTableName: process.env.DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_TABLE_NAME,
  }),
  new DataSource({
    name: 'accountDbConnection',
    type: strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_TYPE') as any,
    host: strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_HOST'),
    username: strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME'),
    password: strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD'),
    database: strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_DATABASE'),
    port: +strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_PORT'),
    synchronize: false,
    entities: [strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_ENTITIES')],
    migrations: accountMigrations,
    migrationsRun: strict('DATABASE_ACCOUNT_MIGRATIONS_RUN') === 'true',
    migrationsTableName: process.env.DATABASE_ACCOUNT_MIGRATIONS_TABLE_NAME,
  }),
];
```

```
"typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli",
"typeorm:account": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -c accountDbConnection",
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- -d ./ormconfig.ts migration:generate ./src/modules/database/migrations/$npm_config_name",
"migration:generate:account": "npm run typeorm:account -- -d ./ormconfig.ts migration:generate ./src/modules/database/migrations/$npm_config_name",
```

We get an error:

'Error: Given data source file must contain export of a DataSource instance'

There is a solution - to create several files with datasets and specify the desired dataset, but I would not want to do this.
Surely there is a better way